# Background notification also get muted on removing "sound" from presentationOptions in @capacitor-firebase/messaging?

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, capacitor

I'm working on a Capacitor app and using [@capacitor-firebase/messaging](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor-firebase/messaging) for push notifications.

My expected output is: I want to show background notifications with sound and handle foreground notifications using the "notificationReceived" listener to schedule a local notification, but only on specific screens.

My app had same functionality using [@capacitor/push-notifications](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor/push-notifications) since it is not supporing silent notification iam trying to migrate from the plugin.

Here's what I've tried so far:

When I set presentationOptions to an empty array like this:

```
FirebaseMessaging: {
  presentationOptions: [],
},
```

I get no sound for both foreground and background notifications.

If I include "sound" in presentationOptions like this:

```
FirebaseMessaging: {
  presentationOptions: ["sound"],
},
```

Now, both foreground and background notifications make a sound.

My question is: How can I configure presentationOptions or use another method to allow sound for background notifications while keeping foreground notifications silent?

my whole capacitor.config.ts file is given below

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from "@capacitor/cli";

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: "com.myapp",
  appName: "myapp",
  webDir: "www",
  bundledWebRuntime: false,
  plugins: {
    FirebaseAuthentication: {
      skipNativeAuth: false,
      providers: ["phone"],
    },
    FirebaseMessaging: {
      presentationOptions: [],
    },
  },
  server: {
    hostname: "myapp.in",
    androidScheme: "https",
    allowNavigation: ["myapp.in"],
  },
  ios: {
    cordovaLinkerFlags: ["-ObjC"],
  },
 
};

export default config;
```